# Initialising a subclass from a abstract type

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a small classifier program.
However what data I have is not completely decided so I'm trying to make the code as generic as possible. 
I'm running into this problem.

I have basically 3 classes

```
abstract class AbstractPoint{}
abstract class AbstractCluster{}

class Classifier{
addPoint(AbstractPoint pt){...}
}
```

I'm fine up to this point.
However in the classifier class if the points fit a certain pattern
I need to create a cluster to add the points into.
but its not possible to instantiate a object based on a abstract class. 
Is there any good methods/patterns? or other ways this could be done?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're after, but you might be looking at a factory pattern. Would it be possible to add a method to `AbstractPoint` that can return the appropriate concrete `AbstractCluster`?

Comment: It sounds like you'll need some concrete classes as well as these abstract ones.  Maybe you should write one or more classes that extend `AbstractCluster`, that you can actually instantiate.

Comment: I think a factory pattern is exactly what I'm looking for! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
    abstract class AbstractPoint{  public abstract void doThings();}
abstract class AbstractCluster{ 
    AbstractPoint[] points;
    public abstract void setPoints(AbstractPoint[] points);
    public AbstractPoint[] getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}

class Classifier{
public void addPoint(AbstractPoint pt){
    pt.doThings();
}
public void addPointsToCluster(AbstractCluster cl,AbstractPoint[] points) {
    if(condition)   //your condition of pattern matching
    cl.setPoints(points);
}
}
```

Comment: I need to initialise a Cluster inside classifier.